# Count substring occurrences within a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a cell?

For example:

```
|   |         A         |
| 1 |John,John,Tom,David|
```

What formula would I use if I want to return the number of occurrences of "John" in cell A1 (=2)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, after searching around for a month on this problem, I stumbled upon the answer after posting this question.  Here is what I came up with in case anyone else has this problem.

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("John"; SPLIT(A1; ",")));1;0))
```

This is an array formula so will need to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If anyone thinks of a better way to solve this problem, please let me know!

Comment: How to do this for multiple cells? so if you would have multiple cells like A1?

Comment: The SPLIT function works outside of VBA?

Comment: Dosn't work in Excel 2013 saying "that function (i.e. `SPLIT`) is not valid".  And the parameters in the functions should be separated by `,` not `;`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an approach that works in Google spreadsheets:

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(A1,","),"John")
```

Comment: Is this specific to certain versions of Excel?  I was not aware that SPLIT works outside of VBA.

Comment: @fixer1234: I think this only works in Google spreadsheets. I've clarified the answer.

Comment: Does not work for me in Google Spreadsheet. The only one I found to work on Google Spreadsheet from this page is @variant's answer.

Comment: Works for me: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSankYnnJpPNS58orPiD6SoYaGLiEC2eHViRB-Bfahc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably found the best way.

An alternative:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"John",)))/LEN("John")
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, using LEN.  Will keep this strategy in mind, when considering other problems.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer I had to use for Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

**Only for Google Sheets**

I came up with the following alternative way:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"@";"");"John";"@");"[^@]";""))
```

Explanation:

- We choose a special character (can be any character not in the target sub-string) and remove it from the string
- We replace the sub-string we are searching for with this char
- We replace any character that is not our special character with nothing
- We count the length of the resulting string and this is the number of occurrences of the sub-string.

Comment: You're right sorry about that as I found this thread seeking a solution for a problem with Google Sheet I didn't even think about excel ... it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The code given by @erwaman has to work with delimiters.

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(A1,","),"John")
```

The alternative code given by @variant doesn't need delimiters.

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"John",)))/LEN("John")
```

I was working with cells that had a list separated by commas. I needed to count how long the list was and the second bit of code worked like a charm.

If the string you are searching for happens to be 1 character like "," or " " you can simplify it to this.

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment in the above thread, but I was able to extend JohnL's answer so that it works on multiple cells:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(find ("search text", split(Concatenate(A1:A3), ","))),1,0)))
```

where `A1:A3` are the cells and "search text" is the text to search.