# How to count occurences of "&nbsp;" in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I was given a spreadsheet containing a bunch of HTML lines sampled below.

```
<nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../Descriptive_Addresses.htm"><b>address: descriptive service location</b></a></nobr><br>
<nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../State_or_Possession_Postal_Abbreviations.htm"><b>address: state</b></a></nobr><br>
<nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../Street_Abbreviations.htm"><b>address: street</b></a></nobr><br>
<nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../Acronyms.htm"><b>approved for contacts</b></a></nobr><br>
<nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../Military_Addresses.htm"><b>armed forces</b></a></nobr><br>
```

Each line begins with one to four occurences of `&nbsp;`.

I need to COUNT *only* the number of occurences of `&nbsp` in each cell; this drives indentation later on.

Using this formula, `=SUM(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&nbsp;","")))/LEN("&nbsp;")` Excel appears to be counting the instances of ALL spaces, not just those defined by `&nbsp;`. See the example below.

[image: My results]

Similar count-substring-within-cell solutions, like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/167113/excel-google-spreadsheet-count-substring-occurrences-within-a-cell) freak out because I'm using reserved characters within my search string.

Any suggestions about how to delineate the two flavors of spaces--`&nbsp;` and a space-bar-space in my formula?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: Please check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/167113/excel-google-spreadsheet-count-substring-occurrences-within-a-cell) question & answer.

Comment: @speakr good link, but I'll be clarifying my question. It's more about differentiating between a space and &nbsp; in a cell.

Comment: @dwwilson66: Can you please clarify this **"Are you looking for number of occurences of &nbsp;"** OR **only spaces ( )** OR **both**?

Comment: As @SivaCharan says, your formula works to count just the occurrences of `&nbsp`.  I'm not sure why you think it's counting spaces as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm chalking it up to Excel getting stupid on me. I cut-and-pasted the data to a new spreadsheet, and viola...my results matched @SivaCharan's instead of my wonky results from yesterday.

Thanks for verifying that the formula WAS correct...it forced me to look elsewhere for the problem!

Comment: if his answer was correct, or helped you find the answer in a substancial way, please mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Man, you folks are too quick for me, @JourneymanGeek. Your msg came through while I was waiting for a refresh to do just that... :)

Comment: lol. It was an interesting question ;p

Comment: I just wish there was a real answer. Non-reproducable glitches are the BEST. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking only number of occurences of **`&nbsp;`** then your formula is working as expected.

```
=SUM(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&nbsp;","")))/LEN("&nbsp;")
```

Refer the screenshot:-

[image: Formula with count]